# Problema al insertar tipo Time en Java

Tags: java, jquery, momentjs

Tengo un atributo duracion en Java que es tipo Time y en el front utilizo una libreria de bootstrap para seleccionar la hora la cual manda como string en formato "12:00:00" y esto tengo que convertir a tipo time para java y no estoy pudiendo.

Estoy intentando con Jquery y moment

Comment: SimpleDateFormat es tu amigo.

Comment: Pero eso es en lado de Java? hay un problema en el sistema que se realiza aca y por eso necesito formatear del lado del frontend con moment, js o lo que sea @JDev

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss

Comment: @JDev no me funciono, me tira error. tengo lo siguiente:

 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        res.setDuracion((Time) df.parse(this.hora));

hora es de tipo string "10:00:00" y tira el error: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Time

Comment: para parsear en java utiliza esto: `java.sql.Time myTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf(string);`